# WebGL glfx.js matrix transform (perspective) crops the image if it rotates

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix, webgl, perspective

I am using the glfx.js library in order to use matrix transformation to create the perspective effect for my images. In my app, the system works just like photoshop's smart objects (where you render a flat image and get perspective results after render)

glfx.js uses this function `canvas.perspective(before, after)` to apply matrix transforms to images, by assigning before and after coordination of the 4 points in an image, and it runs the Matrix command in the background to transform my image.

My issue is that if the resulting image that I want after the transformation applied to it is bigger than the original image (happens if you rotate the image) then the WebGL canvas is going to crop my image.

Look at the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/human_a/o4yrheeq/

```js
window.onload = function() {
    try {
      var canvas = fx.canvas();
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
      return;
    }

    // convert the image to a texture
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var texture = canvas.texture(image);

    // apply the perspective filter
    canvas.draw(texture).perspective( [0,0,774,0,0,1094,774,1094], [0,389,537,0,732,1034,1269,557] ).update();

    image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // or even if you replace the image with the canvas
    // image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, image);
    // image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/glfx.js"></script>
<img id="image" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485207801406-48c5ac7286b2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&fit=max&s=9bb1a18da78ab0980d5e7870a236af88">
```

Any ideas on how we can make the WebGL canvas fit the rotated image (not make the image smaller) or somehow extract the whole image instead of the cropped one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##More pixels

There is no cover all solution. This is because when you convert from 2D to 3D the size of the projected image can possibly approch infinity (near clipping prevents infinity) so no matter how large you make the image output there is always the possibility of some clipping being applied.

With that caveat out of the way there is a solution for most situations that can avoid clipping. It is very simple, just expand the canvas to hold the additional content.

###Find the bounds

To simplify the calculations I have changed the after array to a set of normalised points (they represent the after coords as a scale factor of the image size). I then use the image size to convert to real pixel coordinates. Then from that I workout the min size a texture needs to be to hold both the original image and the projection.

With that info I just create the texture (as a canvas) draw the image. Adjust the befor array if needed (in case some projection points are in negative space) and apply the filter.

So we have an image object that has a width and a height. And you have the projection of those points.

```
// assuming image has been loaded and is ready
var imgW = image.naturalWidth;
var imgH = image.naturalHeight;
```

The set the corner array (before)

```
var before = [0, 0, imgW, 0, 0, imgH, imgW, imgH];
```

The projection points. To make it easier to deal with I have normalised the projection points to the image size

```
var projectNorm =  [[0, 0.3556], [0.6938, 0], [0.9457, 0.9452], [1.6395, 0.5091]];
```

If you want to use the absolute coordinates as in the fiddle's after array use the following code. The normalisation is reversed in the snippet after then next, so you can skip the normalisation. I have just updated the answer quickly as I am short of time.

```
var i = 0;
var afterArray = [0,389,537,0,732,1034,1269,557];
const projectNorm = [];
while (i < afterArray.length){
     projectNorm.push([
         before[i] ? afterArray[i] / before[i++] : before[i++],
         before[i] ? afterArray[i] / before[i++] : before[i++]
     ]);
}
```

Now calculate the size of the projection. This is the important part as it works out the size of the canvas.

```
var top, left, right, bottom;
top = 0;
left = 0;
bottom = imgH;
right = imgW;
var project = projectNorm.map(p => [p[0] * imgW, p[1] * imgH]);
project.forEach(p => {
    top = Math.min(p[1], top);
    left = Math.min(p[0], left);
    bottom = Math.max(p[1], bottom);
    right = Math.max(p[0], right);
});
```

Now that all the data we need has been gathered we can create a new image that will accommodate the projection. (assuming that the projection points are true to the projection)

```
var texture = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = texture.getContext("2d");
texture.width = Math.ceil(right - left);
texture.height = Math.ceil(bottom - top);
```

Draw the image at 0,0

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, left, top); // put origin so image is at 0,0
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
```

Then flatten the projection point array

```
var after = [];
project.forEach(p => after.push(...p));
```

Move all points into positive projection space

```
after.forEach((p,i) => {
    if (i % 2) {
        before[i] += -top;
        after[i] += -top;
    } else {
        before[i] += -left;
        after[i] += -left;
    }
});
```

The final step is to create the glfx.js objects and apply the filter

```
// create a fx canvas
var canvas = fx.canvas();
// create the texture 
var glfxTexture = canvas.texture(texture);
// apply the filter
canvas.draw(glfxTexture).perspective( before, after ).update();
// show the result on the page
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

###Demo

Demo of your snippet using the above method (slight modification for image load)

```js
// To save time typing I have just kludged a simple load image wait poll
waitForLoaded();
function waitForLoaded(){
    if(image.complete){
        projectImage(image);
    }else{
        setTimeout(waitForLoaded,500);
    }
}
function projectImage(image){
    var imgW = image.naturalWidth;
    var imgH = image.naturalHeight;
    var projectNorm =  [[0, 0.3556], [0.6938, 0], [0.9457, 0.9452], [1.6395, 0.5091]];
    var before = [0, 0, imgW, 0, 0, imgH, imgW, imgH];
    var top, left, right, bottom;
    top = 0;
    left = 0;
    bottom = imgH;
    right = imgW;
    var project = projectNorm.map(p => [p[0] * imgW, p[1] * imgH]);
    project.forEach(p => {
        top = Math.min(p[1], top);
        left = Math.min(p[0], left);
        bottom = Math.max(p[1], bottom);
        right = Math.max(p[0], right);
    });
    var texture = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = texture.getContext("2d");
    texture.width = Math.ceil(right - left);
    texture.height = Math.ceil(bottom - top);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, left, top); // put origin so image is at 0,0
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    var after = [];
    project.forEach(p => after.push(...p));

    after.forEach((p,i) => {
        if (i % 2) {
           before[i] += -top;
           after[i] += -top;
        } else {
            before[i] += -left;
            after[i] += -left;
        }
    });
    // create a fx canvas
    var canvas = fx.canvas();
    // create the texture 
    var glfxTexture = canvas.texture(texture);
    // apply the filter
    canvas.draw(glfxTexture).perspective( before, after ).update();
    // show the result on the page
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

```css
#image {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/glfx.js"></script>
<img id="image" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485207801406-48c5ac7286b2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&s=9bb1a18da78ab0980d5e7870a236af88">
```

###Notes and a warning

> **Note** that the projection points (after array) do not always match the final corner points of the projected image. If this happens the final image may be clipped.

> **Note** This method only works if the before points represent the exterme corners of the original image. If the points (before) are inside the image then this method may fail.

> **Warning** There is no vetting of the resulting image size. Large Images can cause the browser to become sluggish, and sometimes crash. For production code you should do your best to keep the image size within the limits of the device that is using your code. Clients seldom return to pages that are slow and/or crash.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however, As I explained in my questions, the functionality I require from this transformation is a system to mimic the smart objects in Photoshop, and those coordinations (before and after) are the only way for me to accurately place the transformed image where I wish them to be (imagine the image to be transformed is going to be a customized image serving as a cover of a book eg.) Did you use a formula to transform the after array to projectNorm? If so, would please explain how to so?

Comment: @HumanA. I have updated the answer. Normalising is just dividing by the image dimensions eg `x / image.width` and `y / image.height`

Comment: Thank you very much. Most parts of your answer was not applicable in my case, but your answer made one thing clear for me, that I can use a canvas as my WebGL texture, and not just an image, which made it possible for me to rotate (transform) the image inside a transparent environment since I already had the width and the height of the final image to be rotated (transformed). Anyways, thank you very very much for your thorough explanation.